# IPsec tunnel gets connected, Phase 2 is successful but no IP adapter is created thus tunnel does not work

Tags: vpn, routing, ipsec, strongswan, tunnel

I am trying to establish an IPsec tunnel between my virtual server and a customer's server. The IPsec tunnel gets established successfuly in Phase 2, but no IP gets added to my system.

This is the ipsec.conf file:

`conn hidden
  auto=add
  keyexchange=ike
  authby=psk
  type=tunnel
  left=WAN IP of our server
  leftsubnet=10.13.255.0/0
  right=WAN IP of the host server
  rightsubnet=0.0.0.0/0
  ike=aes256-sha256-ecp521
  ikelifetime=28800s
  dpdaction=restart
  esp=aes256-sha256-ecp521
  lifetime=3600s`

My client PC is supposed to have 10.13.255.8 and the GW should be 10.13.255.1.
However I get these 2 lines in syslog

Nov 16 14:58:41 esl-server-1 charon: 15[KNL] getting a local address in traffic selector 10.13.255.0/24
Nov 16 14:58:41 esl-server-1 charon: 15[KNL] no local address found in traffic selector 10.13.255.0/24

I am using Strongswan and running on Ubuntu.

Any input is greatly appreaciated. I will gladly provide other relevat log files if necessary.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

`leftsubnet=10.13.255.0/0` is probably not what you intended as that results in `0.0.0.0/0`. So the peer can narrow it to anything, but the narrowed subnet `10.13.255.0/24` is also not ideal if you want to reach the peer's IP address in the same subnet (or the peer wants to reach other clients in that subnet).

Better might be to just configure the specific traffic selector i.e. `leftsubnet=10.13.255.8/32`.

But note that since this address is not negotiated as virtual IP via configuration payloads, you have to add it manually to a local interface (e.g. `lo`). Then it should be found and a route that sets it up as preferred source address will be configured.

Comment: I have changed the configuration based on your advice. I have also set up an IP address of 10.13.255.8 to the main network adapter manually (enp1s0) and then the VPN profile has been attached to this network adapter. However I still cannot ping the gateway (10.13.255.1) 

ip route show table 220
10.13.255.0/24 via PUBLIC_IP dev enp1s0 proto static src 10.13.255.8 - is this the correct way?

Comment: Yes, that route looks OK. Check the traffic counters in the status output. If the counter for the outbound traffic increases, the issue is at the other end.

Comment: Thank you. Do you mean this?

0 bytes_i, 5206 bytes_o

Comment: Yes, that means traffic is sent (`_o` or outbound) but none is received (`_i` for inbound). So the issue is presumably at the other end.

Comment: It works perfectly. However another issue has come up. When the IPsec tunnel gets established, since my primary network adapter is now hooked up in IPsec, no other traffic gets into the server as Strongswan sets the table 220 like this: default via 212.158.144.65 dev enp1s0 proto static src 10.13.255.8. Is there any solution to this or am I missing something? Thank you.

Comment: You could change `rightsubnet` to the subnet(s) you actually want to tunnel traffic to (as long as the responder accepts that).

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. It works flawlessly. Have a great day!